# Adding an image to a model

Tags: texturing

So I've created an object and I used the uv image editor to create the majority of the texture, but now i am needing to add a logo to part of the object.  I tried exporting the uv image so i can edit it in photoshop, but because my object is so complex, I cant make sense of what to do with it...

do any of you have a suggestion on what I can do? or can you tell me how to get the image onto the object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create an image texture then simply assign the material to the face you want the logo on. Pictures would be helpful.

Comment: More details needed, please show at least your setup, how your object makes so complex to edit the uvmap image

Comment: if @NickBosse suggestion does not work because of the layout of your faces you can create a new UV with just the face/faces that are required for your logo. Just remember to set the UV input Node (and give it a helpful name)

Comment: Try to paint a mark on your image , where the logo should be. Export it and you will get the right place to put the logo.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have mentioned- you can try adding a mesh as a shrink wrap modifier. Use a Png to add the logo on top of it. since there's less details on your question - cant really say what the requirement is :\

Comment: Thank you all so much for the quick response! this was my first post on here. I think the reason the geometry is so complex is because I have no idea what I am doing. I have only been using blender for just over a month. I created the mesh, then used sculpt mode to make my shirt look more like fabric. I don't quite understand how to add an image for me to show you what I am doing wrong.